# calculate lat/lon point

Tags: math, gps, coordinates

If I have the coordinates of a point (lat lon) and the azimuth angle how can I calculate what points are at "the end' of a distance of 10 miles.

Ex. I am watching North , I know I am at a certain point ... At 10 miles apart what coordinates has that geo point ?

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) has a pretty good collection of formulae.  For your case,

Let lon1,lat1 be the starting point, θ the azimuth angle (also often referred to as the "bearing") in radians, 
d the distance traveled (km), and R the earth's radius (approx 6371 km). Then you can find 
the final coordinates lon2, lat2 :

`lat2 = asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d/R) + cos(lat1)*sin(d/R)*cos(θ))`

`lon2 = lon1 + atan2(sin(θ)*sin(d/R)*cos(lat1), cos(d/R)−sin(lat1)*sin(lat2))`

Note: d/R represents an angle in radians corresponding to the arc length d.

θ is measured such that North=0 degrees, East=90 degrees, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't make much sense. Let's take the first formula

```
lat2 = asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d/R) + cos(lat1)*sin(d/R)*cos(θ))
```

`sin(lat1)*cos(d/R)` -> as sin and cos will never be larger than 1, the largest result can be 1
`cos(lat1)*sin(d/R)*cos(θ)` -> same as above: the biggest possible result is 1

=> the result is that `lat2` according to that formula can be 2 at most.

Comment: @carter: Did you miss the arcsine in the lat2 formula?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also have a bearing to calculate this distance as well. For very short distances, great circle distance (the distance along the path of the earth) will be very close to cartesian distance, but the site provided by Jim Lewis' answer is a nice interactive site. This site also has a very extensive set of lat/lon formulas http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm.